# No matching function for call to ‘std::less<int>::less(const int&, const int&)’

Tags: c++, class, templates

I tried to write:

```
#include <functional>

template<class T, class func = std::less<T>>
class Car {
public:
    void check(const T& x, const T& y) {
        func(x, y);            //.... << problem
    }
};


int main() {
    Car<int> car;
    car.check(6, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

And my meaning here was that it will recognize the usual `<` for `int`, but it says where I marked:

> no matching function for call to ‘std::less::less(const int&, const 
>        int&)’

But if I create a `Car` with customize `func` then it works... How Can I fix that?

Comment: edited that the parameters are `T`'s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you need an instance of `func` since `std::less<T>` is a functor (i.e. class type) and not a function type.  When you have

```
func(x, y);
```

You actually try to construct an unnamed `std::less<T>` with `x` and `y` as parameters to the constructor.  That is why you get

> no matching function for call to ‘std::less::less(const int&, const int&)’

as `std::less::less(const int&, const int&)` is a constructor call.

You can see it working like this:

```
#include <functional>

template<class T, class func = std::less<T>>
class Car {
    func f; 
public:
    void check(const int& x, const int& y) {
        f(x, y);
        // or
        func()(x, y); // thanks to Lightness Races in Orbit http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit
    }
};


int main() {
    Car<int> car;
    car.check(6, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3aec8a4c3f003909)</kbd>

Comment: Perhaps also clarify that it's a class type (i.e. that of a functor) rather than a function type. For extra teachingz

Comment: IOW, clarify that the "call" `func(x,y)` attempts to construct an object of type `std::less<T>`.

Comment: @Stabilo No problem.  Glad to help.